# Ansible Query how to query inside JSON output

Tags: json, parsing, ansible, vmware, vcenter

I'm asking to a URL API and passing to output to a register. This should be a JSON output.
The first variable "vcclust" JSON, I can extract the "item.cluster" as it's just one level, bad the second output "vchosts" looks, I cant parse to get "item.name" from it and get the hostnames

This is the code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "vcenter_hostname"
    prompt: "Enter vcenter hostname"
    private: no
  - name: "vcenter_user"
    prompt: "Enter vcenter username"
    private: no
  - name: "vcenter_pass"
    prompt: "Enter vcenter password"
    private: yes
  - name: "cluster_touched"
    prompt: "Enter cluster name"
    private: no

  tasks:
  - name: Login in to vCenter and store login information
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/com/vmware/cis/session"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      method: POST
      user: '{{ vcenter_user }}'
      password: '{{ vcenter_pass }}'
      status_code: 200
      validate_certs: no
    register: login
  - name: Get vCenter cluster ID for {{ cluster_touched }}
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/cluster?filter.names={{ cluster_touched }}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        Cookie: '{{ login.set_cookie }}'
    register: vcclust
  - name: Get ESXi nodes from cluster ID for {{ cluster_touched }}
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/host?filter.clusters={{ item.cluster }}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        Cookie: '{{ login.set_cookie }}'
    register: vchosts
    with_items:
    - '{{ vcclust.json.value }}'
  - name: Modify root local user to ESXi
    vmware_local_user_manager:
      hostname: '{{ item.name }}'
      username: root
      password: '{{ esxi_pass }}'
      local_user_name: root
      local_user_password: '{{ esxi_new_pass }}'
      validate_certs: False
    with_items:
    - '{{ vchosts.json.value }}'
```

And this is the output of the debug the vchosts and vcclust

vcclust:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vcclust": {
        "changed": false,
        "connection": "close",
        "content_type": "application/json",
        "cookies": {},
        "date": "Mon, 11 Jun 2018 09:50:43 GMT",
        "failed": false,
        "json": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "cluster": "domain-c310",
                    "drs_enabled": true,
                    "ha_enabled": false,
                    "name": "DB-CLUSTER"
                }
            ]
        },
        "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
        "redirected": false,
        "status": 200,
        "url": "https://vcenter01.lab.test/rest/vcenter/cluster?filter.names=DB-CLUSTER"
    }
}
```

vchosts:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vchosts": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "changed": false,
                "connection": "close",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "cookies": {},
                "date": "Mon, 11 Jun 2018 09:50:45 GMT",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "attributes": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "body": null,
                        "body_format": "raw",
                        "client_cert": null,
                        "client_key": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "dest": null,
                        "directory_mode": null,
                        "follow": false,
                        "follow_redirects": "safe",
                        "force": false,
                        "force_basic_auth": true,
                        "group": null,
                        "headers": {
                            "Cookie": "vmware-api-session-id=56fa6d3015150212b086917d15165bee;Path=/rest;Secure;HttpOnly"
                        },
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "mode": null,
                        "owner": null,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "return_content": false,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "status_code": [
                            200
                        ],
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "unsafe_writes": null,
                        "url": "https://vcenter01.lab.test/rest/vcenter/host?filter.clusters=domain-c310",
                        "url_password": null,
                        "url_username": null,
                        "use_proxy": true,
                        "validate_certs": false
                    }
                },
                "item": {
                    "cluster": "domain-c310",
                    "drs_enabled": true,
                    "ha_enabled": false,
                    "name": "DB-CLUSTER"
                },
                "json": {
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "connection_state": "CONNECTED",
                            "host": "host-312",
                            "name": "vmh19.lab.test",
                            "power_state": "POWERED_ON"
                        },
                        {
                            "connection_state": "CONNECTED",
                            "host": "host-313",
                            "name": "vmh20.lab.test",
                            "power_state": "POWERED_ON"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
                "redirected": false,
                "status": 200,
                "url": "https://vcenter01.lab.test/rest/vcenter/host?filter.clusters=domain-c310"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The error I got is:

```
ansible (ansible_test) ✗)ansible-playbook site.yml
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Enter vcenter hostname [vcenter01.lab.test]: 
Enter vcenter username : 
Enter vcenter password : 
Enter cluster name [DB-CLUSTER]: 

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Start SSH service setting for an ESXi Host in given Cluster] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Login in to vCenter and store login information] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get vCenter cluster ID for DB-CLUSTER] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get ESXi nodes from cluster ID for DB-CLUSTER] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'drs_enabled': True, 'cluster': 'domain-c310', 'name': 'DB-CLUSTER', 'ha_enabled': False})

TASK [Modify root local user to ESXi] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'json'"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/jv/Workspace/vmware-powershell/ansible/site.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tried 

  with_items:
    - '{{ vchosts.results.json.value }}'

but the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json_query`. For that, you might need to install `jmespath` on your ansible host. You can do it with `pip install jmespath`.

```
 - name: Get ESXi nodes from cluster ID for {{ cluster_touched }}
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/host?filter.clusters={{ item.cluster }}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        Cookie: '{{ login.set_cookie }}'
    register: vchosts
    with_items: "{{ vcclust | json_query('*.value') }}"

  - name: Modify root local user to ESXi
    vmware_local_user_manager:
      hostname: '{{ item.name }}'
      username: root
      password: '{{ esxi_pass }}'
      local_user_name: root
      local_user_password: '{{ esxi_new_pass }}'
      validate_certs: False
    with_items: "{{ vchosts.results | json_query('*.value') }}"
```

Comment: Also I tried to check what the value inside 
- debug:
      var: "{{ item.name }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ vchosts | json_query('*.value') }}"
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Modify root local user to ESXi] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

Comment: try use vchosts.results on that 'Modify root local user' task. I edited my original answer aswell.

Comment: TASK [Modify root local user to ESXi] ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/jv/Workspace/vmware-powershell/ansible/site.yml': line 70, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Modify root local user to ESXi\n    ^ here\n"}
 to retry, use: --limit @/Users/jv/Workspace\vmware-powershell/ansible/site.retry

Comment: If I try
- debug:
    var: '{{ item.name }}'
    with_items:
    -  "{{ vchosts.results | json_query('*.value') }}"
I got 
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

Comment: When using var on debug, you should use item.name without quotes and '{{ }}'. When using msg, then you use "{{ item.name }}". Which version of ansible you're using? I tested on my local environment and it did work with vchost.results...

Comment: My version is ansible 2.5.4

Also I tried with  
 - debug:
    var: item.name
    with_items:
    -  "{{ vchosts.results | json_query('*.value') }}"

but same result
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Kelson Silva

you pointed the clue to the answer.

I dont know why this

```
- debug: var=item.name
    with_items:
    -  "{{ vchosts.json.value }}"
```

is not the same as

```
- debug: 
    var: item.name
    with_items:
    -  "{{ vchosts.json.value }}"
```

and actually that was driving me crazy, this is for sure a bug in this version of ansible

the problem is that it was tooking the elements in my first request as list inside a Json and you need to enumerate them.

In order to dont get a dirty "vchosts" JSON you need to use just one element from "vcclust", so the code end like:

```
  - name: Get vCenter cluster ID for {{ cluster_touched }}
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/cluster?filter.names={{ cluster_touched }}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        Cookie: '{{ login.set_cookie }}'
    register: vcclust

  - name: Get ESXi nodes from cluster ID for {{ cluster_touched }}
    uri:
      url: "https://{{ vcenter_hostname }}/rest/vcenter/host?filter.clusters={{ vcclust.json.value[0].cluster }}"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      validate_certs: no
      headers:
        Cookie: '{{ login.set_cookie }}'
    register: vchosts

  - name: Modify root local user to ESXi
    vmware_local_user_manager:
      hostname: '{{ item.name }}'
      username: root
      password: '{{ esxi_pass }}'
      local_user_name: root
      local_user_password: '{{ esxi_new_pass }}'
      validate_certs: False
    with_items:
    -  "{{ vchosts.json.value }}"
```